# SWT.MouseWheel event works in Eclipse Development Environment but not in other environments

Tags: java, event-handling, integration-testing, swt, mousewheel

I am experiencing an issue with the `SWT.MouseWheel` event specifically in environments other than Eclipse Development Environment. The event handler for `SWT.MouseWheel` functions correctly within Eclipse, but it fails to work in other environments. Here are the details and steps I have taken:

In Eclipse, the code snippet below registers the `SWT.MouseWheel` event handler:

```
ccombo.addListener(SWT.MouseWheel, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        // Code logic for handling mouse wheel scrolling
        // This code functions properly within Eclipse 
    }
});
```

I have verified that the `SWT` library version used is consistent between both environments.

I have confirmed that the `CCombo` widget has focus when the mouse wheel is scrolled in other environments.

Despite these checks, the event handler for `SWT.MouseWheel` fails to execute outside of Eclipse. I have attempted to debug the code, but no relevant error messages or exceptions are displayed.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into why the `SWT.MouseWheel` event fails to trigger in environments other than Eclipse, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

I am unsure of the reason behind this behavior, and I'm looking for guidance on how to debug this situation. Here is some information I have gathered:

- The eclipse development environment is using JRE version 1.6.0.45.
- The integration environment is using JRE version 1.8.0_60_b27.

I suspect that the issue may be related to differences in JRE versions. I would like to understand how this affects the triggering of the `SWT.MouseWheel` event and how I can debug this situation.

If you have any ideas, suggestions, or experience with a similar issue, please share them. I appreciate any help in resolving this problem.

Comment: What version of SWT is this? Java 1.6 was end of life in 2015 I wouldn't expect the current SWT to work with it at all. For that matter Java 8 is now on update 361 so 60 is also way out of date.

Comment: `3.4.1` on integration and `3.7.2` on eclipse development environment

Comment: Sorry but all that stuff is ancient. As far as I can see MouseWheel works fine on my system but that is using the SWT from Eclipse 4.28 with Java 20 (on macOS 13.4.1)

Answer (score -1):

It appears that I have encountered an issue related to the behavior of `CCombo` in SWT.

The problem is that mouse wheel scrolling doesn't work on `CCombo` due to a conflict with window scroll events.

One possible way to solve this problem is by creating a subclass of `CCombo` and overriding the mouse wheel event handler. Here's an example code that can help you resolve this issue:

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class ScrollableCCombo extends CCombo {
    public ScrollableCCombo(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);

        // Add the mouse wheel listener to handle scrolling
        addListener(SWT.MouseWheel, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                if ((getStyle() & SWT.READ_ONLY) != 0 && isMouseInsideCCombo(event.x, event.y)) {
                    // Change the selected item on mouse wheel event
                    int selectionIndex = getSelectionIndex();
                    int itemCount = getItemCount();
                    if (itemCount > 0) {
                        // Calculate the new selection index based on the scroll direction
                        int scrollCount = event.count;
                        int newSelectionIndex = selectionIndex - scrollCount;
                        newSelectionIndex = Math.max(0, Math.min(itemCount - 1, newSelectionIndex));

                        // Set the new selection index
                        select(newSelectionIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isMouseInsideCCombo(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
        Point ccomboLocation = getLocation();
        int ccomboWidth = getSize().x;
        int ccomboHeight = getSize().y;

        return mouseX >= ccomboLocation.x && mouseX <= ccomboLocation.x + ccomboWidth &&
                mouseY >= ccomboLocation.y && mouseY <= ccomboLocation.y + ccomboHeight;
    }
}
```

`ScrollableCCombo` class can be used instead of `CCombo` in code. It extends `CCombo` and adds a mouse wheel event handler to handle scrolling through the combo box items.

Example usage of `ScrollableCCombo`:

```java
// Replace the creation of CCombo with ScrollableCCombo
ScrollableCCombo ccombo = new ScrollableCCombo(shell, SWT.READ_ONLY);
ccombo.setItems(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" });
```

This should allow you to scroll through the combo box items using the mouse wheel without conflicting with window scroll events.-